# How do I debug App crash [H10] on Heroku for a node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am quite new to Heroku so forgive me if this is a silly question, I am running a home made node.js web proxy server on Heroku and sometimes I get lots of H10 (App crashed) messages in the log. Most of the time the app seems to be able to recover itself (restarts?) but sometimes it ends up in some sort of a crash loop and I have to go in and restart the dyno manually. Im running hobby dyno and I guess that doesn't allow me to scale up or add redundancy options, but I want to find out what is causing the app to crash. The app deploys fine and starts as it should, the problem occurs in runtime when its serving client requests.

In the Heroku log i only see very basic info, very similar to this example from Heroku support: "`heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd=17.17.17.17 dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=`"

It would useful to understand where the app crashed so that I can find and solve the root cause. (or could the problem be lack of resources at Heroku?)

Again, I have only a very basic knowledge about Heroku and programming in general.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error should be with the `procfile`.

Please check for the `procfile`, if it is pointing to the wrong server file.

A [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) should be a text file, called Procfile, sitting in the root directory of your app.

It should specify the command Heroku should use to start your app.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I didn't find a procfile, but I have a package.jason file that specifies the startup command. The app starts just fine, the problem is that it occasionally crashes when its up and running serving requests.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to find more info about this? We're encountering a similar issue, random H10 errors while running.